# textbox text as html for an email in c#

Tags: c#, email

I am trying to send an smtp email from my c# web site. it sends fine all except when a textbox text has line breaks in it it does not format these in the email.. instead it just has one long string of text.

the email is html encoded so how do i make this:

tbDeliver.Text

keep the line breaks in the email?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
var textBoxText = tbDeliver.Text.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br>");
```

Answer (score 4):

I do this with a regular expression to make sure I get any flavor of newline:

```
Regex matchNewLine = new Regex("\r\n|\r|\n", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.Singleline);
string result = matchNewLine.Replace(originalText, "<br />");
```

Answer (score 2):

make sure that the body format of the message is of type Html. if you are using system.web to send mail :

```
System.Web.Mail.MailMessage mail = new System.Web.Mail.MailMessage();
mail.BodyFormat = Web.Mail.MailFormat.Html;
```

if you are using system.net :

```
    System.Net.Mail.MailMessage mail = New System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
    mail.IsBodyHtml = True;
```

Comment: yup using .Net and i have that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could replace `\r\n` in .Text with `<br/>` that might work, do you output in a paragraph `<p>`?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to replace `\n` with `<br>` in `tbDeliver.Text`.

```
string formatted = tbDeliver.Text.Replace ("\n", "<br />");
```

Answer (score 0):

Html encode the linebreaks to '<br/>' or '<p>' tags.

Answer (score -1):

ACK!

**NEVER EVER EVER** use Environment.NewLine to replace <BR> tags in email.

I can't stress this enough.

On some platforms, Environment.NewLine will be \n's, which is a huge no-no in the SMTP world.

In SMTP, all line breaks must be \r\n.

Eventually, your mail will get rejected as spam by some servers using only \n.

**always use \r\n or vbCrLf to replace <br> tags.**

Comment: You are reading the question wrong. The newline does NOT come from or is put into an email but comes from the form on the page. The email is constructed from a form which has a textbox which needs to be included in the email. The textbox will have `Environment.NewLine` as a line delimiter. That indeed can be `\r\n` or `\n` depending on platform. Since OP hasn't specified platform `Environment.NewLine` is the best option. This newline (from the nextbox) is converted to `<br>`.